# Ajax pop-ups are not interactable and sized improperly

Tags: drupal-8, ui

Before reporting a bug, I just wanted to double check if it's anything obvious or localized.

The mailing preview pop-up and the "add activity" pop-up from the contact page are two examples of broken functionality on our site. They just don't work. The frame does, you can move it around and close it, but actual interactions with the content don't. It's like it's locked or there was a div over it blocking event dispatch.
[image]

Eg. that internal scrollbar doesn't work. If I zoom out enough in firefox for the scrollbar to disappear, that doesn't help anything. Can't click or input. I also don't see any problematic elements in the DOM nor are there any javascript errors logged.

Am I the only one with such problems? Is the port of the theme incomplete? I couldn't find any related bug reports. CiviCRM 5.24 on Drupal 8.8.

Answer (score 1):

What theme are you using in drupal 8. Some things look weird in bartik but I haven't noticed this problem. In the meantime, you can go to Administer - Customize - Display Preferences and turn off popups. It's a checkbox near the bottom underneath WYSIWYG editor: "Enable Popup Forms".

Comment: The theme is custom, but thanks for the preference tip — it's a valid workaround.